# Uploading an image to s3 via paperclip from an attachment sent by the sendgrid API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, sendgrid

I'm creating a rails app where people can send photos to my service. The Sendgrid API posts the info to my controller.

One of the params is the attached image. I want to create a new post (@post = Post.new), posts have attached photos (paperclip). I want to take the attached image and use that as the image for the post. I can only find examples where people use a form to create a model and the form passes an image. They do something like @post = Post.new(params[:post]). This won't work for me as I need to match the info from Sendgrid to my model.

@post = Post.new
Post.photo = params[:attachment] doesn't work

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`:attachment` shouldn't actually contain the image.  It should be in the format `:attachmentX`.

See our parse API docs for reference: http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/parse-api-2/

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for trying to help me out. All of the Paperclip example I see show people making a form, then submitting that form's data to some controller. If I did that, I could use post = Post.new(params[:post]). However, my data isn't coming from a form, it's coming from the SendGrid parse API. I need to pick out the pieces of data that are useful to me and ignore the rest. I'm having a hard time because I can't do something like this... post = Post.new; post.name = params[:name]; post.image = params[:attachment]; etc...